# Flags not being updated since I got "vote-to-close" privilege

Tags: support, flags

I've noticed that the amount of helpful flags hasn't been rising lately, and I sure like to flag stuff. When I visited my flagging history, I saw that there's only 1 flag [of a comment] in the last **~10 days**.

About that time, I've surpassed **3k reputation** thus earning the [close questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) privilege. At this point I started thinking that maybe voting to close and flagging the question are **not the same thing**.

So I started flagging again, instead of closing - the result remain the same, and my `flag` menu looks exactly as the one for voting to close, the **submit button** even says "VOTE TO CLOSE" on most of the flags which I use - duplicates, off-topic, too-broad. Only **rude or abusive** and **in need of moderator intervention** keep being called "FLAG".

Is there any particular reason why this is happening?

Comment: IIRC, if you _flag_ to close when you have close privileges, it gets automatically turned into a close vote instead. I'll see if I can find a source for that.

Comment: @Kendra it does... and also I can't see any other flags in the history that could be marked helpful to increase the count...

Comment: Well they're not in the history at all, not even "waiting for approval". I have flagged / voted to close several questions for sure. Some of which have probably been closed, but nothing shows up, that's why I asked.

Comment: The irony of flagging a question about flags is inevitable...

Comment: @Vucko not a flag.  A close vote.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As soon as you click "should be closed" from within the "flag" menu, you get teleported to the "close" menu.

Close *flags* are different to close *votes*. Once you surpass 3k, you lose the ability to flag, and instead you vote. You can view your close *votes* at https://stackoverflow.com/users/5647037/vucko?tab=votes&sort=closure

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understand. Similarly when you surpass 2k, you get no +2 reputation for editing, just edit for the sake of it. I was wondering how should one achieve the badges for flags when all the **decent** flags are taken from me at this point? :D

Comment: @Vucko there's always stuff that's not an answer or potentially spam/abusive etc... there's more reasons to flag than just question closure :)

Comment: @Vucko Answer and comment flags are your best bet at the badges now. Alternatively, you _could_ post bounties until you're under 3k again, flag until your rep hits 3k once more, then repeat.

Comment: Haha @Kendra thanks for the bounties suggestion, but I'd rather keep my reputation over a gold badge :D Ok, was just wondering, thanks for your time guys. Best regards! :)